# What's the best way to keep a distinct record for each user in Android?

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

In my app, each user has a table of records says:
`id, friend_name, message`

My goal is to store this data in Android phone, so that each time a user log in, he/she can populate this list quickly. At server side, I already had a record of `friend relationship`...etc. Now I just want to keep a small database in Android side for each user because loading from the server takes times, plus I realize that these data are distinct among users. Let's says:
- User A has messages: a, b, c
- User B has messages: d, e, f
...

I read about `SharePreference`, but I guess it's inappropriate here since SP is only good for `key/pair` values. Then I look over `sqllite` database, it's straightforward. But what I don't understand is how can we make sure that each time a new user log in, he/she will have his/her own database but not others? I can keep a `key/pair` value `flag` for each user in `SharedPreference` to check if the database already existed, but then where do I store these databases? For `n` users, I would have to store `n` databases, that sounds impractical.

So what's the best way to store my data in this case?

Comment: Maybe you could try save not record for each user, but for each message, becaues as I understand the messages can be connected with more than one user. Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't create a new database for each user. What you need to focus on is good database design. In this particular case you would create a table for messages, a table for users and a table that holds links between users and messages using their ids. When a user logs into your app, you would find the messages that are linked to this user. A good database design also makes sure there is no redundant data (=duplicate data, for instance storing the same message twice). Look into database normalization if you want to learn more about that.

Comment: But if I would have to create a database across all users, then it's just like using the server database. In my server database, I have `user` table, `friend` table which store a pair of ids, and a `message` table. Apparently, I can do a `JOIN` query, but I still want to keep a distinct data record for each user. I wonder is there any other technique for this particular case? By the way, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UUID.getRandomUUID() behaviour. I have seen this at GOOGLE I/O Protips movie.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=twmuBbC_oB8